# Determining if calendar resource legacy data is a meeting room

Tags: google-admin-sdk

How can one determine for legacy data if a returned item is a meeting room?

The [calendar resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars) says that a `resourceCategory` will be set to "CATEGORY_UNKNOWN" for legacy data.  This means the typical check of `resourceCategory == "CONFERENCE_ROOM"` to determine if a resource is a conference room will not work for legacy data.

One thing I've noticed in my own organization is that `resourceType == "Conference room"` for legacy data.

Is the `resourceType` a reliable source to determine if a resource is a room?  In other words, is the "Conference room" I'm seeing in the `resourceType` field a choice Google provides, or is it customizable by the user?

If `resourceType` isn't the right field to look at, is there another way to reliably determine if legacy data is in fact a meeting room?

Thanks!

Comment: [resourceType](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars) is "writable" so that means you can specify it when making POST/PUT/write requests.

Comment: Good point, so `resourceType` isn't reliable.  Do you know of a way to determine if legacy data is a meeting room or not?

Comment: my knowledge is as far as the docs go.